# How to hide the listing of posts under the category page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have description in all the categories page in my wordpress blog. I want to disable the listing of posts in the category page. I tried using css,

```
 .inside-article{
 display:none;
 }
```

But this hides content inside all pages and posts.
I want only the post listing to be gone in category, and not even in tags.

Comment: Check what classes WordPress generates on the body element for these page types, pretty sure there will be something that lets you identify those category pages. Then use that class in a CSS rule that targets your elements only if they are descendants of a body element with that class.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't want content in a page at all, hiding it via CSS is not the desired solution. Instead, this content should be removed "for real" directly from the applicable template file.

Here's a description of WordPress' template hierarchy: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/. Most probably you should edit the `category.php` file. If it does not exist, you can create one by cloning the `archive.php` file, which should be there in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out in css., Although I would suggest the answer by Zoli, that content should be removed for real.
This is the code I tried in CSS

```
.category .inside-article { display:none; }
```